# doing an rsync across multiple machines

Tags: ssh

I have the following setup: Machines A, B , C running linux. I have to do a continuous rsync from machine A to machine C and have a script for that. However, the access to machine C from machine A is only through B. So I have to ssh into B and then I can ssh into C.

The way to rsync that I have now is that first I rsync from C to B and then rsync from B to A. However, with the additional copy between the machines, this is

Comment: "With the additional copy between the machines, this is..." This is what? I think I know what you're trying to ask, but please finish your question...

Answer (score 3):

You can use netcat for this. Here's an example setup:

On machine A, your ~/.ssh/config looks like this:

```
Host            machinec.whatever.domain.com
ProxyCommand    /usr/bin/ssh machineb /usr/bin/nc %h %p
```

(with any addition of IdentityFile or anything else that you may require)

This will let you rsync straight through machine B; netcat/nc will forward the entire data stream for you. Of course, this requires that `nc` be available in that path on machine B.